# How do i track usage of a heap table ?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to look at something similar to sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats (This DMV is only for tables with indexes I believe) for the Heap tables? Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heaps are tracked in `sys.indexes` and `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` with `index_id=0`.  Try

```
select 
   db_name(database_id) database_name,
   object_name(object_id,database_id) table_name,
   s.*
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats as s
where index_id = 0
```

You should see your heap tables.